# Configuring socket.io for node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a few questions about configuring socket.io for my node.js application.

1. When requiring `var socket = require('socket.io')( /* HERE */ )`, do I need to input the port my server listens where the `/* HERE */` is at?
2. Right below the above line, I have another require function, for a .js file that contains a few constants and a function (see below). When I try to refer to 'socket' in that file it says it's undefined. But since this line is below the require line for the socket.io middleware seen above, why does it say 'undefined'?

   ```
   const numbers = '1234'
   function asd(req,res,next) {
     socket.emit('a')
   }

   module.exports = {
     asd
   }
   ```
3. For configuring client-side socket.io, I added this line:

   ```
   var socket = io.connect('https://mydomain')
   ```

   Do I need to say 'mydomain:port' or is 'mydomain' enough?

Comment: can you post your entire code ?

Comment: post it for what?

Comment: `post it for what?` ?? you do realise your code is required for debugging, right ?

Comment: You need to post your code so we figure out, together, what went wrong and why. This is a **programming** related help site, therefore we need code. You'll get help that you're after if you post code, not if you post explanations.

Comment: Posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use socket.io

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = http.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

var port = 8081;


io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('event1', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('event2', { msg: 'delivered' });
    });


});


app.listen(port);
```

**Answer to your second question**

Yes, you will need to specify the port you are using

```
 <script src="socket.io.js"></script>

 <script>
     var socket = new io.Socket();
     socket.connect('https://mydomain:8081')

     socket.on('your_event',function() {
         console.log('your_event receivid from the server');
     });
 </script>
```

Here socket will connect to port 8081

**This is a simple server side code**

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
var port = 8081;

// Start the server at port 8081
var server = http.createServer();

server.listen(port);


var socket = io.listen(server);

// example listener
socket.on('event_2', function(client){ 
    console.log('event_2 received');
});

// example emitter
socket.emit('event_1', { hello: 'world' });
```

Comment: That wasn't my question.

Comment: I guess you answered 1, but not 2 and 3.

Comment: @konyv12 have you installed the `socket.io` npm module ?

Comment: I have, otherwise it would be hard to use it.

Comment: Does the port need to be the same as the server is running on? Because I have just set it to that, and I get an error message that 'port is already in use'.

Comment: the port you specify in `app.listen(port)` should be the same port you connect to on client end  ( `socket.connect('https://mydomain:port')` )